# Is it a sin to study talmud as a woman?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, women, torah-study

In the movie Yentl, a woman pretends to be a man in order to study talmudic law. Is it considered a sin to study the talmud as a woman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not considered a sin for a woman to study Talmud on her own.

The Talmud does question the wisdom of one's teaching one's daughter Talmud; however the *Prisha* comments that if a woman chooses to study of her own volition, that's fine.

Comment: What about in a yeshiva?

Comment: @J.Doe: Talmud study in a group, such as in yeshiva, is preferable since the dialog helps one to refine their understanding. There are a number of women's yeshivot, such as Nevey Yerushalayim, Mayanot, and Bais Chana Women International. The only reason for disguising as a man in the movie Yentl, is that the men's yeshivot tend to feature a more advanced Talmud program, while the women's tend to have a broader variety of subjects such as scripture and ethics.